# laravel shared hosting access denied for user root in cpanel using password:no

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

```
**DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=konyayal_yalcinsurucu
DB_USERNAME=konyayal_yalcinsurucuadmin
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxx**
```

no ssh and terminal option on my hosting.how can i solve?

Comment: Have you tried connecting with a client from your machine to the MySQL server on Cpanel?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check in .env file is everuthing is correct or not like username and password of database.

Once confirm from .env try to execute this command on server =>

1. php artisan optimize:clear OR sudo php artisan optimize:clear

it will clear all the cache from your projects and take new values from .env and set in cache system.

I hope you will solve your problem of access denied with this small help.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work.I don't have a terminal on my hosting, I applied it locally and reinstalled it

Comment: You can do in other way by creating a separate route and call that route on web.
`Route::get('clear_cache', function () {
    \Artisan::call('optimize:clear');
    dd("Cache is cleared");
});`